# Unscramble string in C

Tags: c, string, words

I am pretty new to C, and I thought I would try to make a program which unscrambles a string input to reveal a real word and I have it working, but with some words I get unexpected results. Here is an example of it working correctly:

> Enter Word:stop
>
> Match: opts
>   Match: post
>   Match: pots
>   Match: spot
>   Match: stop
>   Match: tops

I am using a word list that I got from a program called "aspell" which allowed me to create a file full of words. What's strange is when I enter a word like "test" or "football" the response brings back words that have letters that don't originally exist in the input word. What am I doing wrong here? The following is my unscrambleWord function, which does most of the work. Also, I will post the "football" example

```
int unscrambleWord(int fgLetters) {

        // integer used for the counter
        int i = 0;

        // first make sure that the lengths of the word and of the list word is the same
        if(strlen(currentLine) == strlen(input)) {

                // loop through each letter in the word given
                for(i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {

                        // search the line for the current letter, if we find it increment fgLetters
                        if(strchr(currentLine, input[i]) != NULL)
                                fgLetters++;

                } // end for

                // once we have finished looping through the word; evaluate fgLetters
                if(fgLetters == strlen(input)) {

                        // fgLetters will be equal to the length of the word if each letter appears in the word
                        printf("\tMatch: %s \n", currentLine);

                } // end if - evaluate length of fgLetters

        }

    // return the fgLetters after we have possibly incremented it
        return fgLetters;

}
```

Here is the football example:

```
Enter Word:football

Match: blastoff 
Match: boastful 
Match: flatboat 
Match: football 
Match: lifeboat 
Match: softball
```

For some reason, there are s's in the match strings, but the number of characters seem to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This algorithm gives false positives.

Every letter of the word `football` is in the word `softball`. But that doesn't mean you can reorder the letters to change the word. You match the two `o`s to the same `o` letter.

An easy way to find matches is to sort the letters and see that you get the same word.

```
football -> abflloot
softball -> abfllost
```

Answer (score 2):

You're allowing repeated letters to get over-counted.  In `football` for instance there are two 'o's and two 'l's, and so you allow the s and u in boastful.

In C code it's usually wise to grab the result of `strlen` once and use that in your loop, too, rather than calling it repeatedly.  Only the smartest of C compilers notice that `strlen(word)` is the same on each trip through the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking if a letter from the source is contained in the current line, but not if there are letters in the current line that are not in the input. You also need to handle letters that are there more then once (in the input and in the line from the word list).

Comment: This is the best explained answer I think, so perhaps I need to run through the "for" loop twice, but switching the input and currentLine variables?

Comment: well it's a wrong answer.. even if you would check you could still get false positives. (eg: `goo` and `gog`). check my answer.

Comment: Use Karolys answer. Sort the input and the current line and compare. It doesn't get easier then that.